# merge finite sorted list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I am wondering how to write a function in Haskell that accepts finite sorted list of integers and merge them (sorted). Any code is appreciated!

Comment: [`sum`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=sum). But honestly, this can't be your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your goal is just to merge two list this is not so complicated

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

this says that `merge` takes two lists and produce a list for any type with a defined ordering relation

```
merge [] x = x
merge x [] = x
```

this says that if you merge the empty list with anything you get that anything

```
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | y < x     = y : merge (x:xs) ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | otherwise = x : merge xs (y:ys)
```

this says that `if` when you merge two lists the first element of the second list is lower, that should go on the front of the new list, and otherwise you should use the first element of the first list.

EDIT: Note that unlike some of the other solutions the merge above is both `O(n)` and *stable*.  Wikipedia it if you don't know what that means.

If your goal is to merge a list of lists you generally want to do this bottom up by merging two lists at a time

```
mergePairs :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
mergePairs [] = []
mergePairs [ls] = [ls]
mergePairs (x:y:ls) = (merge x y):mergePairs ls

merges :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
merges [] = []
merges [x] = x
merges ls = merges $ mergePairs ls
```

it can be shown that this is asymptotically optimal if all the initial lists are the same length (`O(m n log n)` where `m` is the length of sorted lists and `n` is the number of sorted lists).

This can lead to an asymptotically efficent merge sort

```
mergeSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
mergeSort ls = merges $ map (\x -> [x]) ls
```

Comment: But how is this O(n)? I doubt it's effcient :/. Can you provide me the keyword? What is x:xs?

Answer (score 6):

This should do it, without requiring that the lists be finite:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x < y
                        then x:(merge xs (y:ys))
                        else y:(merge (x:xs) ys)
merge [] xs = xs
merge xs [] = xs
```

In english, check the first elements of each list, and make the lesser one the next element, then merge the lists that remain.

Answer (score 1):

```
(sort . concat) [[30..32],[1..3]] == [1,2,3,30,31,32]
```

Comment: This is short and neat, but I think the complexity will be worse than @PhilipJF's answer. You're not making use of the fact that the input lists are sorted.

Comment: You're exactly right. And concat is O(n^2) I believe. Simple merge is O(n).